# Unable to compile C program with static library

Tags: c, linker-errors

I am trying to run the following command:

```
gcc -static urlor.c libtest.a -o urlor-test
```

Using the following two files:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/oqjmwdzj2axwo62/AACvLhYCC97lE0W1b0Yq09xva?dl=0

in my urlor.c file I do this:

```
#include <test/tstree.h>
#include <test/bstrlib.h>
```

when I check the contects of my libtest.a:

```
$ar -t libtest.a
tstree.o
bstrlib.o
```

I have tried many different commands but nothing worked.
It either doesn't recognize when I include the necessary header files or it says "undefined references to function `XXXXXX`"

What am I doing wrong? is the library broken? am I not linking it correctly? does this work for you?

Comment: Please include the actual code in your post.

Comment: Yes, that is what you are supposed to do.

Comment: Or just RTFM: `-static` is for *making* libraries. If you just want to *use* the library that's in your directory (and assuming its header files are there as well), try `gcc -I. -L. urlor.c -o urlor-test -ltest`.

Comment: I worked with this guide: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/gcc/create_lib.html. and also tried what you just suggested with the same results

Comment: And where is `tstree.h` and `bstrlib.h`? You need to provide those as well. In case you aren't aware, the headers are source files and are not located in the library.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: GCC 5.2.0 manual for [Linking options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) says: _`-static` On systems that support dynamic linking, this prevents linking with the shared libraries. On other systems, this option has no effect._  This is not the antithesis of `-shared`, which is for creating shared objects.  On the other hand, if there is a `libtest.a` static library, that's what'll be used regardless of whether the `-static` option is used or not.  Dropping `-static` may help.  Reporting (a sample of) the actual errors will help.

Comment: @AlanAu do you mean that I need to add them to libtest.a?
JonathanLeffler - I got "fatal error: tstree.h: No such file or directory" and when I didn't get that, I got "undefined reference to function ..."

Comment: @YotamAlon No! You need to have those header files in the same directory tree as your `urlor.c` file.

Comment: Tried that as well with same results...